# display contact with given display name android

Tags: android, contacts

SO,how do i do it? I have tried the following

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT);
intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("mailto","example@email.com", null));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

The above works only with mailto or tel, what about name?

Answer (score 2):

you can also send Person Name using `Intents.Insert.NAME` with Intent as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT);
intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("mailto","example@email.com", null));
// add name here
intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.NAME, sender_Name_here); 
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: umm it doesnt work.  No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.contacts.action.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT (has extras) }